# If user is logged in redirect to dashboard using React router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-redux

I am trying to implement a redirect solution. If a user has already logged in and tries to visit the homepage(visible to everyone) I want to redirect to the dashboard(visible to only logged in users).

My current solution:

```
export const PublicRoute = ({ auth, ...props }) => {
    const isAllowed = auth.isLoggedIn();
    return isAllowed
        ? <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
        : <Route {...props} />;
};
```

Usage:

```
<PublicRoute
    auth={{ isLoggedIn: () => AuthService.isLoggedIn() }}
    path="/"
    component={Main}
/>
```

Private Route Component:

```
export const ProtectedRoute =  ({ auth, ...props }) => {
    const isAllowed = auth.isLoggedIn();
    return isAllowed
        ? <Route {...props} />
        : <Redirect to="/login" />;
};
```

However, when this is excecuted I get the following warning:

> Warning: You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on:
>   "/dashboard"

Routes:

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={History}>
        <Switch>
            <PublicRoute
                auth={{ isLoggedIn: () => AuthService.isLoggedIn() }}
                exact={true}
                path="/"
                component={Homepage}
            />

            <PublicRoute
                auth={{ isLoggedIn: () => AuthService.isLoggedIn() }}
                path="/login"
                component={Login}
            />

            <ProtectedRoute
                auth={{ isLoggedIn: () =>  AuthService.isLoggedIn()}}
                path="/dashboard"
                component={Dashboard}
            />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
</Provider>
```

Why am I getting this error when I'm redirecting from the homepage to the dashboard?

Comment: You need to wrap the routers in Switch, `import { Switch } from 'react-router-dom';`

Comment: @Liam I did wrap in a switch component.

Comment: The reason could be that from your protectedRoute you are trying to redirect back to /dashboard whereas you were already there

Comment: What does the PublicRoute do, when isAllowed false, it renders the Route else redirects to dashboard???

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri 
Yes if it's false it renders the route specified in the path props else redirect to the dashboard

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to use `()` to render the Route, you need to change like that:

```
export const PublicRoute = ({ auth, ...props }) => {
    const isAllowed = auth.isLoggedIn();
    return isAllowed
        ? (<Redirect to="/dashboard" />)
        : (<Route {...props} />)
};
```

Private Route Component:

```
export const ProtectedRoute =  ({ auth, ...props }) => {
    const isAllowed = auth.isLoggedIn();
    return isAllowed
        ? (<Route {...props} />)
        : (<Redirect to="/login" />)
};
```

Comment: Thanks, the issue was the missing parans `()`.